# How to merge different rows of different tables into a new one

Tags: r

I got these two tables (A and B) of a `data.frame (df).`

Table A

```
             bb  cc    dd    W   ee   Y
vaccined     12  17.2  15.3  14  5.1  9
no_vaccined  13  7.8   9.7   11  24.9 16
NA           0.3 0.6   1.3   0   0.5  0.7
```

Table B

```
    bb   cc   dd ee  
no  91.5 90.8 95 87
yes 8.5  9.2  5  13
```

Notes: In Table B, 'yes' represents the number of subjects who belong to a certain criteria in percentage (e.g "<5 years old"). **Please note that Table B has no 'W' nor 'Y' variables**

I would like to merge these two tables into one. But: I would only like to add to the new table (C) the "yes" row of Table B and to keep "W" and "Y" variables of table A.

Example:

```
             bb   cc    dd    W  ee    Y
vaccined     12   17.2  15.3  14  5.1  9
no_vaccined  13   7.8   9.7   11  24.9 16
NA           0.3  0.6   1.3   0   0.5  0.7
yes          8.5  9.2   5     25  13   25.7
```

Is there any possible way of doing this?

Any help would be considerably helpful.

Comment: I could help you, but you would have to give me some reproducible data.  Look at the `dput()` function.

Comment: In general, I think what you're looking for is rbind.fill from the plyr package. Try rbind.fill(table_a,table_b). But @Raphael K is right, you need a reproducible example for us to know exactly what you want.

Comment: Where are the `W` and `Y` values for the `yes` row in the merged data.frame coming from? Sums of the other rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# sum up W and Y
# and add sum(Y) and sum(W) to B in the same column-order as in table A:
B_new<- cbind(B[, 1:3], W=sum(A$W),ee= B[, 4], Y=sum(A$Y))

rbind(A, B_new[2, ])
              bb   cc   dd  W   ee    Y
vaccined    12.0 17.2 15.3 14  5.1  9.0
no_vaccined 13.0  7.8  9.7 11 24.9 16.0
NA           0.3  0.6  1.3  0  0.5  0.7
yes          8.5  9.2  5.0 25 13.0 25.7
```

First you adjust table B to look like table A, by adding the two columns `Y` and `W` using `cbind`. As you showed in your expected output the values are summed up, respectively. You use the `sum` function for this. Then you can `rbind` A and B (only the "yes" row) togehter.

Answer (score 2):

if table B has `No` and `Yes` as row names, you can probably do the following

```
rows.to.keep<-c("Yes")# you can add more.  
dfC<-which(rownames(dfB) %in% rows.to.keep)
new.df <- rbind(dfA,dfC)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to use `merge` than `rbind` if you don't have the same variables in both data.frames:

```
AB <- merge(A, B[B[, 1] == 'yes', ], all = TRUE)
AB
#           var   bb   cc   dd   ee  W    Y
# 1 no_vaccined 13.0  7.8  9.7 24.9 11 16.0
# 2    vaccined 12.0 17.2 15.3  5.1 14  9.0
# 3         yes  8.5  9.2  5.0 13.0 NA   NA
# 4        <NA>  0.3  0.6  1.3  0.5  0  0.7
```

You also seem to want to impute values for the `NA`s in `W` and `Y` by inserting column sums, which you can do like so:

```
AB[, -1][is.na(AB[, -1])] <- colSums(AB[, -1][,colSums(is.na(AB[, -1])) > 0], na.rm = TRUE)
AB
#           var   bb   cc   dd   ee  W    Y
# 1 no_vaccined 13.0  7.8  9.7 24.9 11 16.0
# 2    vaccined 12.0 17.2 15.3  5.1 14  9.0
# 3         yes  8.5  9.2  5.0 13.0 25 25.7
# 4        <NA>  0.3  0.6  1.3  0.5  0  0.7
```

If what I've read in as `var` here are actually row names, you can drop the `[, -1]`s. You'll need to replace the `[, 1]` in the `merge` with `row.names(B)`, too.

---

#### Data

```
A <- structure(list(var = structure(c(2L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("no_vaccined", 
    "vaccined"), class = "factor"), bb = c(12, 13, 0.3), cc = c(17.2, 
    7.8, 0.6), dd = c(15.3, 9.7, 1.3), W = c(14L, 11L, 0L), ee = c(5.1, 
    24.9, 0.5), Y = c(9, 16, 0.7)), .Names = c("var", "bb", "cc", 
    "dd", "W", "ee", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L))

B <- structure(list(var = structure(1:2, .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    bb = c(91.5, 8.5), cc = c(90.8, 9.2), dd = c(95L, 5L), ee = c(87L, 
    13L)), .Names = c("var", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L))
```